# Cannot compare received user input via read

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "`read -n 1`" == "c" ] ; then
    printf "\nfoo\n"
    exit 0
fi

printf "\nbar\n"
exit 0
```

However, regardless of the input, I always get `bar` as the output:

```
$ ./test.sh
c
bar
$ ./test.sh
d
bar
```

Why is this occuring and what do I need to change in the shell script?

Comment: Deleting the spaces around the operator `==` works fine for me. Also, prefer `echo` instead of `printf` for displaying unformatted strings.

Comment: @Bentoy13 It's not a syntactic error, but comparing the integer exit status of `read` to the string `c` will *always* fail; it's not a useful operation.

Comment: @chepner It was sounding too easy ... I can't figure out why I have then the correct behaviour with my syntactic trick. But never mind, the choosen answer is indeed the thing to do. Also, your explanation of what is wrong in the OP is quite clear, it's a good introduction for any answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read it into a variable first, otherwise you're just comparing the `output value` of read (which is empty value).

Following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -n 1 ch
if [ "$ch" == "c" ] ; then
    printf "\nfoo\n"
    exit 0
fi

printf "\nbar\n"
exit 0
```

Comment: Actually comparing the _output_ of the read command, rather than the return value, but that would be nothing too.